# why memcpy alters the string array?

Tags: c++

I have code which goes like this. Could you tell me why it is not behaving as I would expect it to be?

```
/*
 * test.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Dec 6, 2012
 *      Author: sandeep
 */

#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    string s="hello A B:bye A B";
    char *input;
    input=new char(s.size());
    for(i=0;i<=s.size();i++)
        input[i]=s[i];
    char *tokenized1[2],*tokenized2[3];
    tokenized1[0]=strtok(input,":");
    tokenized1[1]=strtok(NULL,":");
    i=0;
    char *lstring;
    while(i<2)
    {
        lstring=new char(strlen(tokenized1[i]));
        memcpy(lstring,tokenized1[i],strlen(tokenized1[i])+1);
        cout<<tokenized1[0]<<"  "<<tokenized1[1]<<endl;
        tokenized2[0]=strtok(lstring," ");
        tokenized2[1]=strtok(NULL," ");
        tokenized2[2]=strtok(NULL," ");
        char c=tokenized2[0][0];
        cout<<c<<endl;
        cout<<tokenized2[0]<<"  "<<tokenized2[1]<<"  "<<tokenized2[2]<<endl;
        i++;
    }

}
```

and the output is this.

```
hello A B  by
h
hello  A  B
hello A B  by
b
by
```

There are some junk values at the end of 1st, 4th and 6th line of output.
Why `tokenized1[1]` got altered when I I did memcopy of `tokenized1[0]`? and how to solve this?

Comment: 2 points: 1) I really don't see why this question is tagged both c and c++. From the code it looks pretty much c++. 2) When using c++, why would you use `memcpy`, manual memory management, `strlen` and so on instead of `std::copy` and operations on `std::string`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple of bugs in the following `new` call. You need to use square brackets; also, the argument is off by one.

```
lstring=new char[strlen(tokenized1[i]) + 1];
```

Without the square brackets, your are allocating space for *one* character. As a result, the `memcpy()` writes past the allocated memory.

**edit:** I just noticed the other `new`, which will also need to be fixed:

```
input=new char[s.size() + 1];
```

Finally, `s[i]` reads past the end of the string in:

```
for(i=0;i<=s.size();i++)
    input[i]=s[i];
```

There could well be other bugs, not to mention memory leaks...

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be zero terminating 'input'

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what NPE said, there's a couple of other small things:

```
char *input;
input=new char(s.size());
```

This might have something to do with it - you are allocating a *single* character. You then write that one character, and overwrite other memory that is used for who-knows-what. Try this instead:

```
char *input = new char[s.size() + 1];
```

Another issue is your loop, immediately below that:

```
for(i=0;i<=s.size();i++)
        input[i]=s[i];
```

At least on *my* system, using std::string::operator[] with an offset equal to s.size() fails; I don't know about your particular implementation, but I'm pretty it fails as well. Be safe, rather than sorry, and recode your loop thusly:

```
for(i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    input[i] = s[i];

input[i] = 0;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Good luck going forward.